# What does 動ラ下二 means? And how to pronounce it?

Tags: meaning, dictionary

Saw it in a jisho but I have no idea what it means.

Comment: where exacty did you see it?  link/screenshot?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

動{どう}ラ下二{しもに}, an abbreviation of 動詞{どうし}、ラ行{ぎょう}下二段{しもにだん}活用{かつよう}.  That is, a Classical Japanese (文語{ぶんこ}) verb of the “lower bigrade” conjugation, with a root ending in *-r*.

To really understand what this means you need to spend some time learning Classical Japanese grammar.  Many dictionaries have an appendix or something explaining the concepts, and it should be easy to find 文語 guides online.  In English, I recommend Wixted’s *A Handbook to Classical Japanese*.

I can’t make a full introduction to the grammar in the space of this answer, but an example of a verb in this class would be 流{なが}る *nagaru*; it inflects as 流れ、流れ、流る、流るる、流るれ、流れよ.  It’s of course the ancestor of modern *nagareru*.

Notice how in *kana* notation the inflections start with one of two different *kana*, る and れ.  Recall that, in the traditional *gojūonzu* table of *kana* characters, symbols with an *-e* vowel are in the lower half.  So the inflections for this verb, as written in *kana*, use two lines from the lower side of the *r-* column.  That’s what is meant by ラ行 (“*ra* column”) 下二段 (“two lines, lower”).  An adapted translation could be “verb with a root ending in *-r*, whose inflections use the vowels *-u-* and *-e-*”.  (A verb which uses an *-i* vowel to inflect, like 落{お}つ – 落ち、落ち、落つ、落つる、落つれ、落ちよ – would be a 上二段{かみにだん}, “upper bigrade” verb).